# Perl script not saving cookies on google chrome?

Tags: perl, google-chrome, cookies

i am trying to learn to work with cookies using Perl. following is my code. but i dont know why the cookie is not getting saved in chrome. everytime i run this script a new cookie is created.

```
#!"C:\wamp\perl\bin\perl.exe" -w
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
use CGI::Carp qw( fatalsToBrowser );
use CGI;

my $q=new CGI;
$value=$q->cookie('lol');

$cookie=$q->cookie
(
-name=>'lol',
-value=>'gh',
-expires=>'+7d'
);

print $q->header(-cookie=>$cookie);

$q->start_html
(
-title=>'CGI.pm Cookies'
);

unless($value) {print "cookie is goint to set";}
else {print "Hi $value";}

$q->end_html;
exit;
```

Comment: There's a Chrome Extension "Edit This Cookie" that you can use to view cookies, maybe use this to check whether it's being set.

Comment: @barmar, yes, i tried that. The cookie was not there, thats why i am posting here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the output of your script:

```
Content-type: text/html

Set-Cookie: lol=gh; path=/; expires=Sat, 04-May-2013 11:16:12 GMT
Date: Sat, 27 Apr 2013 11:16:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

cookie is goint to set
```

You send the `Content-Type` response header twice: first, on line 2, and again on line 16 when you print `$q->header(-cookie => $cookie)`.

In fact, the double newline on line 2 ends your HTTP headers. So the output of `$q->header(-cookie => $cookie)` will be treated as document body content, *not* as HTTP headers.

Quickest solution? **Comment out line 2**.

Answer (score 2):

Your forgot to send your cookie to the client:

```
print header(-cookie=>$cookie);
```

Comment: I am sorry i somehow missed that line in my code. the code does not work with even header.

Comment: There are several lines in your script that aren't being printed but should be.  Try running it on the command line to make your you are generating the output you think you are.